Find the number of numeric values by row under specific criteria
I have this sample data frame
 df <- data.frame(New=c("X2", "k 5, N 8", "N30","k 6, N 3", "K5", "S12", "K5", "k 1, N 18"),
    K_10=c(NA, NA, 3, 4,0,2,NA, NA), 
    K_11=c(NA, NA, NA, 4,0,3,NA, NA), 
    K_12=c(NA, 2, NA, NA,0,NA,NA,0), 
    K_13=c(0, 3, 5, NA,0,5,NA,NA), 
    K_14=c(NA, 3, 1, 2,10,10,NA,NA),
    K_15=c(NA, 2, 3, 5,15,10,NA,2),
    K_16=c(NA, 10, 1, 6,43,10,NA,56),
    K_17=c(NA, 5, 1, 3,1,10,NA,23),
    K_18=c(NA, 6, 4, 2,0,10,NA,12),
    K_19=c(NA, 3, 8, NA,3,10,NA,90),
    K_20=c(NA, 3, 19, 2,6,10,NA,59),
    K_21=c(NA, 3, 10, 2,8,10,NA,11),
    K_22=c(NA, 3, NA, 2,9,10,NA,10),
    K_23=c(NA, 3, NA, 2,90,10,NA,9))

df
           New K_10 K_11 K_12 K_13 K_14 K_15 K_16 K_17 K_18 K_19 K_20 K_21 K_22 K_23
    1        X2   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
    2  k 5, N 8   NA   NA    2    3    3    2   10    5    6    3    3    3    3    3
    3       N30    3   NA   NA    5    1    3    1    1    4    8   19   10   NA   NA
    4  k 6, N 3    4    4   NA   NA    2    5    6    3    2   NA    2    2    2    2
    5        K5    0    0    0    0   10   15   43    1    0    3    6    8    9   90
    6       S12    2    3   NA    5   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10
    7        K5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
     8 k 1, N 18   NA   NA    0   NA   NA    2   56   23   12   90   59   11   10    9

I want to create some additional columns to the above data.
The first column will check if I have at least 6 numeric values in each row only when the New column gets the fixed structure  "k, N", that is  for "k 5, N 8", "k 6, N 3" and  "k 1, N 18"
The second column will count how many numerical values we have, when  the criterion of the first additional column is satisfied.
The third column will check if I have at most 5 numeric values (1,2,3,4,5) in each row only when the new column gets the fixed structure "k, N", that is "k 5, N 8", "k 6, N 3" and  "k 1, N 18".
The fourth column will count how many numerical values we have when  the criterion of the third additional column is satisfied.
So I want something like
  df_N <- data.frame(New=c("X2", "k 5, N 8", "N30","k 6, N 3", "K5", "S12", "K5", "k 1, N 18"),
    K_10=c(NA, NA, 3, 4,0,2,NA, NA), 
    K_11=c(NA, NA, NA, 4,0,3,NA, NA), 
    K_12=c(NA, 2, NA, NA,0,NA,NA,0), 
    K_13=c(0, 3, 5, NA,0,5,NA,NA), 
    K_14=c(NA, 3, 1, 2,10,10,NA,NA),
    K_15=c(NA, 2, 3, 5,15,10,NA,2),
    K_16=c(NA, 10, 1, 6,43,10,NA,56),
    K_17=c(NA, 5, 1, 3,1,10,NA,23),
    K_18=c(NA, 6, 4, 2,0,10,NA,12),
    K_19=c(NA, 3, 8, NA,3,10,NA,90),
    K_20=c(NA, 3, 19, 2,6,10,NA,59),
    K_21=c(NA, 3, 10, 2,8,10,NA,11),
    K_22=c(NA, 3, NA, 2,9,10,NA,10),
    K_23=c(NA, 3, NA, 2,90,10,NA,9),
At_least_6=c("Not Applicable","TRUE", "Not Applicable","TRUE", "Not Applicable", "Not Applicable", "Not Applicable","TRUE"),
Count_at_least_6=c("Not Applicable",8, "Not Applicable",6, "Not Applicable", "Not Applicable", "Not Applicable",5),
At_most_5=c("Not Applicable","FALSE", "Not Applicable","FALSE", "Not Applicable", "Not Applicable", "Not Applicable","FALSE"),
Count_at_most_5=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)              )


 df_N

    New K_10 K_11 K_12 K_13 K_14 K_15 K_16 K_17 K_18 K_19 K_20 K_21 K_22 K_23     At_least_6 Count_at_least_6      At_most_5 Count_at_most_5
1        X2   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA Not Applicable   Not Applicable Not Applicable               0
2  k 5, N 8   NA   NA    2    3    3    2   10    5    6    3    3    3    3    3           TRUE                8          FALSE               0
3       N30    3   NA   NA    5    1    3    1    1    4    8   19   10   NA   NA Not Applicable   Not Applicable Not Applicable               0
4  k 6, N 3    4    4   NA   NA    2    5    6    3    2   NA    2    2    2    2           TRUE                6          FALSE               0
5        K5    0    0    0    0   10   15   43    1    0    3    6    8    9   90 Not Applicable   Not Applicable Not Applicable               0
6       S12    2    3   NA    5   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10 Not Applicable   Not Applicable Not Applicable               0
7        K5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA Not Applicable   Not Applicable Not Applicable               0
8 k 1, N 18   NA   NA    0   NA   NA    2   56   23   12   90   59   11   10    9           TRUE                5          FALSE               0

Explanation: in the first row of column "Count_as_least" we have the value of 7, because there are 7 values from the sixth value onwards. In other words, we have the first 6 values
8   2    3    3    2   10   

and from the sixth value onwards we have  the values
10    5    6    3    3    3    3    3

which are 8 in total.
The last column is zero as the criterion of the second to last column is not satisfied.
I know that the function counts in dplyr will do the job but I am not sure.
My real data contains thousands of such rows.

You can find out if the row match the condition with sapply and then count with rowsums. In the following code, I use df[, -1] because I exclude the first column New, you can adjust this if the structure of your original df is slightly different. Finally, regarding your Explanation, in the first row of column "Count_as_least", there are 7 values, since you add an initial number "8" that is not in the example df.
library(tidyverse)
df_N <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    # Determine if there are at least 6 numeric values
    At_least_6 = ifelse(grepl("^k \\d+, N \\d+$", New), 
                        rowSums(sapply(df[ , -1], function(x) !is.na(x) & is.numeric(x))) >= 6,
                        "Not Applicable"),
    # Count how many numeric values are at least 6 (subtracting 5)
    Count_at_least_6 = ifelse(At_least_6  == TRUE, 
                              rowSums(sapply(df[ , -1], function(x) !is.na(x) & is.numeric(x))) - 5,
                              "Not Applicable"),
    # Determine if there are at most 5 numeric values
    At_most_5 = ifelse(grepl("^k \\d+, N \\d+$", New), 
                       rowSums(sapply(df[ , -1], function(x) !is.na(x) & is.numeric(x))) <= 5,
                       "Not Applicable"),
    # Count how many numeric values are at most 5
    Count_at_most_5 = ifelse(At_most_5 == TRUE,
                             rowSums(sapply(df[ , -1], function(x) !is.na(x) & is.numeric(x))),
                             0))
df_N
        New K_10 K_11 K_12 K_13 K_14 K_15 K_16 K_17 K_18 K_19 K_20 K_21 K_22 K_23     At_least_6 Count_at_least_6      At_most_5 Count_at_most_5
1        X2   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA Not Applicable   Not Applicable Not Applicable               0
2  k 5, N 8   NA   NA    2    3    3    2   10    5    6    3    3    3    3    3           TRUE                7          FALSE               0
3       N30    3   NA   NA    5    1    3    1    1    4    8   19   10   NA   NA Not Applicable   Not Applicable Not Applicable               0
4  k 6, N 3    4    4   NA   NA    2    5    6    3    2   NA    2    2    2    2           TRUE                6          FALSE               0
5        K5    0    0    0    0   10   15   43    1    0    3    6    8    9   90 Not Applicable   Not Applicable Not Applicable               0
6       S12    2    3   NA    5   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10 Not Applicable   Not Applicable Not Applicable               0
7        K5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA Not Applicable   Not Applicable Not Applicable               0
8 k 1, N 18   NA   NA    0   NA   NA    2   56   23   12   90   59   11   10    9           TRUE                5          FALSE               0

